# Azure Blob Resource Not Found for Access Level Private

Tags: c#, angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

The access level of my container is 'Private (no anonymous access)'. I prefer this access level as I only want authorized users to view my content. However, when I try to access a file via the container URL I get a `ResourceNotFound` error.

I guess there are alternative steps to authenticate the validity of the request. Can someone please help me out by letting me know the steps to get a file displayed.

My front end is Angular/HTML.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You can't directly access a blob if it is in a blob container with `Private` ACL.

What you would need to do is create a [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature) on the blob with at least `read` permission and use the SAS URL of the blob. You can create a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) on the blob.

The way it normally works is that you would create a SAS on the blob in your backend API and then pass that SAS token/URL to your frontend.

Comment: Imagine a case where I get the SAS token/URL and have access to the file (as you described). Therefore, I should be able to take this URL and paste it in any browser to view the content. Right ?

How can I prevent unauthorised users from accessing this content ?

Comment: `Therefore, I should be able to take this URL and paste it in any browser to view the content. Right ? ` - That's correct. `How can I prevent unauthorised users from accessing this content ?` - Please see this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas) for best practices when using SAS.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good pointer. By any chance do you know a blog or a post that shows how this is done ? Sorry but I'm a newbie.

Comment: No worries :). You can use any of the Storage SDKs to create a SAS token. Storage SDKs are available for all the major programming languages (.Net, Java, Node/JavaScript etc.).